# Error using waitforduration function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


var greenBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenball")
 var redBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redball")


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    borderBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = borderBody

 backgroundColor = SKColor.purpleColor()




    //
    var bar0 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar0")
     var bar1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar1")
     var bar2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar2")
     var bar3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar3")
     var bar4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar4")
     var bar5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar5")

   var bars = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar\(arc4random_uniform(6))")




    var bartest = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar0")
    bartest.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.size.height * 0.633)
    addChild(bartest)







    var barra = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 10))
    barra.name = "bar"
    barra.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    barra.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)




    greenBall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX-100, y: frame.midY)
    greenBall.yScale = 2
    greenBall.xScale = 2

    redBall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX+100, y: frame.midY)
    redBall.yScale = 2
    redBall.xScale = 2


    self.addChild(redBall)
    self.addChild(greenBall)
    self.addChild(barra)




    func makeBars() {

        var randomTopOrBot = arc4random_uniform(2)
        if randomTopOrBot == 0 {

            var MaxY = frame.size.height * 0.951
            var MinY = (frame.size.height * 0.633)-bars.size.height
            var Range = CGFloat(MaxY - MinY)
            var barsSpawnX = (frame.midX)
            var barSpawnY =  CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Range)))
            bars.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: barSpawnY)
            addChild(bars)

        } else {

            var MaxY = frame.size.height * 0.951
            var MinY = (frame.size.height * 0.633)-bars.size.height
            var Range = CGFloat(MaxY - MinY)
            var barsSpawnX = (frame.midX)
            var randomBetweenRange =  CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((Range))))
            bars.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: (MinY+randomBetweenRange))
            println(frame.size.height * 0.633)
            addChild(bars)

        }
    }



   let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(3, withRange: 2)
    let spawn = SKAction.runBlock { makeBars <--- this is where it's saying the problem is()

    }

   let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
```

---

edit: So basically I've got 2 spawn locations I'm picking from, I randomly decide between the two with a random number, and now I'm wanting to apply the timer to the function makeBars, but it's telling me I can't reference the local function

---

This is giving me an error that says "cannot reference a local function with captures from another local function".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please post more code?

Comment: Yep, I sort of changed of what I've done. I'll edit it in a second. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me know if you need more. Not even sure exactly where the problem might stem from. Brand spankin' new at this.

Comment: It appears as though you never actually use the `sequence` SKAction. On the last line did you mean to use `self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))` ?

Comment: Oh yep haha, thank you Jonathan! That was a mistake. 

Still having issue with the runBlock { makeBars () giving me that error. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your `makerbars()` method inside the `didMoveToView` method. So it was a function nesting problem after all, given the full code I was able to see the true issue.
Change your code to my modified and corrected version below:

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

```
var greenBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenball")
var redBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redball")


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    borderBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = borderBody

    backgroundColor = SKColor.purpleColor()




    //
    var bar0 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar0")
    var bar1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar1")
    var bar2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar2")
    var bar3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar3")
    var bar4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar4")
    var bar5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar5")






    var bartest = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar0")
    bartest.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.size.height * 0.633)
    addChild(bartest)







    var barra = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 10))
    barra.name = "bar"
    barra.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    barra.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)




    greenBall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX-100, y: frame.midY)
    greenBall.yScale = 2
    greenBall.xScale = 2

    redBall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX+100, y: frame.midY)
    redBall.yScale = 2
    redBall.xScale = 2


    self.addChild(redBall)
    self.addChild(greenBall)
    self.addChild(barra)



    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(3, withRange: 2)
    let spawn = SKAction.runBlock { self.makeBars() }
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
}


func makeBars() {
    var bars = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar\(arc4random_uniform(6))")
    var randomTopOrBot = arc4random_uniform(2)
    if randomTopOrBot == 0 {

        var MaxY = frame.size.height * 0.951
        var MinY = (frame.size.height * 0.633)-bars.size.height
        var Range = CGFloat(MaxY - MinY)
        var barsSpawnX = (frame.midX)
        var barSpawnY =  CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Range)))
        bars.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: barSpawnY)
        addChild(bars)

    } else {

        var MaxY = frame.size.height * 0.951
        var MinY = (frame.size.height * 0.633)-bars.size.height
        var Range = CGFloat(MaxY - MinY)
        var barsSpawnX = (frame.midX)
        var randomBetweenRange =  CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((Range))))
        bars.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: (MinY+randomBetweenRange))
        println(frame.size.height * 0.633)
        addChild(bars)

    }
}


}
```

Comment: Bleh, I thought that made a ton of sense as well. Still getting the same error with your code copy pasted in exactly.

Comment: could you post the rest of your code? from where you declare the class to the end?

Comment: Thanks so much for your time with this haha. I've just posted everything I've got.

Comment: Thank you SO much! New to this and had no idea where to even start with fixing this. Sorry for not posting the entire code at first. Didn't think it would be necessary.

Thanks again, have a great day man.